# How can I create a calculated field that uses the amount of filter items selected in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I am curious if there is a way to make a calculated field that uses the amount of items in a filtered selected. The calculation measure I am trying to do is:

2 x [Amount of Filter Items Selected]

For example, if I have 5 items selected like the filter attached below, it would be 2 x 5 and would therefore have a measure equal to 10 in my data source.

[image]

I am hoping to use this for a capacity dashboard that allows the user the select the dates they want, and then the total capacity auto calculates itself with this created measure. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If your filter is on a dimension `[Current Dates]`, you can make a calculated field

`[Capacity]`:

```
2 * COUNTD([Current Dates])
```

This is view-dependent, and will only work as intended in a view with this filter. Otherwise, `[Capacity]` will be equal to double the number of distinct dates in your total set.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is the [Measure Values] measure where the filter was renamed to Current Dates.